# How to debug javascript which uses GPS from an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, gps, emulation

I have an ASP.NET project.

I have configured IIS Manager so my phone can access my local version (via default bindings).

I access that website via iPhone - On the webpage, there is a get location button which uses GPS to get the values, then puts those values in a text box.

After the textbox has been populated with the location, another button should be enabled (i.e you can press it). But! When I get the location and it is inserted into the textbox, the other button is not enabled.

Javascript is used to handle most of this.

I have no idea why this is happening, and I want to be able to debug the javascript after the GPS location has been populated into the textbox.

On my desktop when I simulate a mobile view (by shrinking window size on chrome), I can see the location button, but when I press it, an error message pops up saying it cannot get location (probably because there is no GPS on desktop).

**How do I debug my javascript when the GPS location has been populated into the textbox?**

Comment: Are you enabling the button once the data is recieved?

Comment: @jeff - yes, but it enables only if the location is valid. For desktop people you enter the postcode, and if it is recognised it will be enabled. Same thing should work for when location is put into the textbox. Want to see what is being run in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am using **Javascript Debugger** extention in Firefox to debug javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Download link :
https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/javascript-debugger/

I am sure there is a similar extension in Chrome